# Azure Table Storage Range query on RowKeys through REST api returns bad request

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

In an ajax request to the Azure Table Storage api I specify the following url

```
url:'https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey=\'2016-01-12_1\')?$filter=RowKey+ge+1',
```

Which gets a bad request response. I have tried several modifications like use plain whitespace between the words in the filter or use `%20` but the result is the same.

I know for sure that this partition exists and that is contains values greater than 1.

If the url is in the form:

```
url:'https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey=\'2016-01-12_1\',RowKey=\'someValue\'),
```

then it works. But I cannot make it work with the filter. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're using it incorrectly. If you specify `PartitionKey` in brackets, then you must use `RowKey` there as well. You can't mix the 2 options.

From [`Querying Tables and Entities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894031.aspx):

> Because the PartitionKey and RowKey properties form an entity's
>   primary key, you can use a special syntax to identify the entity, as
>   follows:

```
https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/Customers(PartitionKey='MyPartition',RowKey='MyRowKey1')
```

If you want to filter on `RowKey` for some `PartitionKey` value, you have to specify the `PartitionKey` in `$filter` only. So your request URL will be:

```
https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable()?$filter=PartitionKey eq 'PartitionKeyValue' and RowKey ge 'RowKeyValue'
```